# Conditional formatting using ruby or python

Tags: python, ruby, google-sheets

Does anybody know how to apply conditional formatting to a google spreadsheet document using ruby or python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, Google does not let python or ruby runs in the browser. Conditional formatting is currently limited to simple rules based on cell contents. Google has recently rolled macros ability in their spreadsheets but that is limited to JavaScript and does not support conditional formatting.

Comment: You can actually use javascript for conditional formatting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958364/google-docs-spreadsheet-automatic-coloring