# Any text in one cell, change color in selected other cells

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I want conditional formatting so that when anything is entered into cell A1 it will change the color of the cell A1 as well as of A8, A14, A21, A27, A33 and A40.

I know how to change the entire column or row, but not specific cells. Or how to phrase the custom formula for any text vs. a specific text.

Comment: I googled this for you... Try it next time. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en

Comment: Should this only apply to column A, or the rest of the columns in the sheet as well?

Comment: Touche'. My comment was perhaps not ideal. Welcome to SO. Please read the [How to Ask Page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with what you have tried. No one here likes re-creating what you have already attempted. You said you know how to change the entire column or row, then show us what you have so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Docs Spreadsheet Automatic Coloring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958364/google-docs-spreadsheet-automatic-coloring)

Comment: It's not automatic based off of what is in the different cells, only based on cell A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Format > Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:

```
=$A$1<>""
```

with formatting of your choice and Range:

```
A1,A8,A14,A21,A27,A33,A40
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I couldn't remember what the formula was for any text. <>"" Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Please try Format > Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:
`=$A5:$A100="NOTPAID"`
Means: if include text "NOTPAID" range in A5 to A100, clour will be changed.

Comment: Beginning like in accepted answer, but formula doesn't solve issue from question